# Serve contents from Nextcloud / WebDAV

Tags: filesystem

I am looking for a solution to show the contents of a folder in a Wordpress site with the folder being hosted on Nextcloud. Since Nextcloud and Wordpress both support WebDAV I thought it would be straight-forward to find a plugin that provides the functionality to list files in a certain directory and make them accessible (via WebDAV).

However, the only WebDAV-related plugins I find are about Wordpress backups.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Since Nextcloud and Wordpress both support WebDAV" In what way does WordPress support WebDAV? I'm not aware of any such support.

Comment: Well, there are many plugins that allow WP backups via WebDAV. Hence, fundamentally it mus be possible to make WP understand WebDAV or am I missing something?

Comment: Well plugins can do almost anything, so yes, but that’s not the same as WordPress having any sort of built in support.

Comment: So what is the bottom-line of this comment?

Comment: Found this while searching for this. Not sure if it works, it's not released as a plugin on wordpress.org. https://github.com/MeiKatz/wp-webdav-media

Answer (score 0):

You could store all your data on a separate server and make that folder available as a SMB (Smaba)-Share. Both, your Wordpress server and Nextcloud can connect to SMB shares. Nextcloud comes with a plugin called "External Storage" which is very flexible.
I keep all my data that way, not inside Nextcloud but on SMB shares which NC connects to. This way, the SMB shares can also be accessed by Windows clients or any other environment, independent of NC.